# How to update JTextArea with JButton without it dulicating

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextarea

I have searched this site, and others looking for an answer.

I have created a GUI to calculate retail discounts. I can enter the information, use the calculate button to perform the calculations, and add it to a list that displays in a JTextArea. Then I use a new item button to clear the areas (except text field). When I click the button "add to list" for a second item it works but puts two copies of the information in the text area. How do get it to only put one copy of information?

Below is the code for the event listener for the "add to list" button

```
  /*
   * Private inner class to handle add to list event
   */

  private class AddListener implements ActionListener
  {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent a)
      {            
          //Get and set sale item name to ItemList object
          String name = saleItem.getName();
          iL.setName(name);
          //Get and set department name to ItemList object
          String dept = dP.getDep();
          iL.setDpt(dept);
          //Get and set original price to ItemList object
          String oP = dsP.getOrg();
          iL.setOp(oP);
          //Get and set sale price to ItemList object
          String sP = dsP.getSale();
          iL.setSp(sP);

          //Add ItemList object to ArrayList
          iList.add(iL);

          final String text = "Sale Item: \t" + iL.getSIname() +
                              "\nDepartment: \t" + iL.getDpt() +
                              "\nOriginal Price: \t$" + iL.getOp() +
                              "\nSale Price: \t$" + iL.getSp() + "\n\n";

          //Add ArrayList to text area
          for(int index = 0; index < iList.size(); index++)
          {
              ItemList iLt = (ItemList)iList.get(index);
              itemL.append(text);
          }   
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You always add all items in the list to the textarea but don´t clear the textarea before.
Try 
`textArea.setText("");`
before the loop in which you call `textArea.append(text)`:

```
      itemL.setText("");  //Clear the textarea before appending the new items.          

      //Add ArrayList to text area
      for(int index = 0; index < iList.size(); index++)
      {
          ItemList iLt = (ItemList)iList.get(index);
          itemL.append(text);
      }   
  }
```

}

Comment: thanks for trying but this did not work. Not only does it still duplicate, but it no longer shows the first entry. I need the program to keep a list of each entry, without duplicates

Comment: Try java.util.Set (HashSet) instead of List(ArrayList). In a set there can´t be duplicates.

Comment: thank you, using a HashSet worked. It took me a little while to figure out how to use a HashSet (and I needed to look-up what is was). But I got it. :)

Comment: I´m glad that i could help you. Please vote the answer or the comment.